# How to test long nested properties method invocation?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

how should I test methods which calling nested property method? Something like:

```
PropertyA.PropertyB.PropertyC.DoSomething();
```

Should I create mock for each property and check if method DoSomething() was called? Looks like a lot of test code for simple method invocation. Is there a better way?

Comment: This smell is called a "Message Chain". It's better to refactor by figuring out what the functionality you're trying to capture and putting that in a separate method (or class): https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/message-chains

Comment: I made some review  and it seems I should accept your answer. It's The Law of Demeter violation and should be avoided. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After small research and @jessehouwing comment turned out that this practice is code smell called "Message Chain" and should be avoided because of The Law of Demeter violation. More info: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/14/law-of-demeter-dot-counting.aspx/

Answer (score 2):

You're right. You have to configure mock for all the objects that you need. The configuration depends according to the mock framework you choose to use.